# Converting a side-effect only function to async using futures. Which is the return type?

Tags: scala, akka

I am working for the first time in a real project using Akka and Scala. While designing an interface for a DAO (which will have two implementations: memory and mongo) I came with the following doubt. Suppose we have a sync version of UserRepository like this

```
trait UserRepository {

  def find(id: Int): Option[User]

  def save(user: User): User

  def delete(user: User): Unit

}
```

and an async version of it would be something like this:

```
trait UserRepository {

  def find(id: Int): Future[Option[User]]

  def save(user: User): Future[User]

  def delete(user: User)

}
```

How would you define the return time of the delete method? Future[Unit]? Future[Any] Future[Void]? What is the best type to return in an async operation which I only care if its side-effects are applied successfully. I don't have nothing to return but I would like to know if the deletion was successfully completed or in case of an exception being able to register an onFailure callback.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use `Future[Unit]` for exactly the same reason that you use `Unit` in the synchronous case—you need to return *something*, but don't have anything you need to return. `Future[Any]` on the other hand means "Here's something, but I won't tell you what it is". And let's not even talk about what `Future[Void]` would mean.

If you don't want to take my word for it, do a quick Google search for [`"Future[Unit]" scala`](https://www.google.com/#q=%22future%5Bunit%5D%22+scala) and you'll find lots of cases of other people using it in [precisely this context](https://github.com/twitter/util/blob/master/util-core/src/main/scala/com/twitter/util/Closable.scala).

You can also find this idiom in the use of `IO ()` in Haskell—where `()` is the unit type and `IO` is in some ways similar to Scala's `Future`—to represent computations where we only care about the side effects.

Answer (score 1):

I use `Future[Unit]` for this. This way you can compose your futures, put in onComplete handlers and  check for errors.